# Selecting row with ROW_NUMBER() window function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently writing a query for a process at my work. I am trying to get specific rows by applying the ROW_NUMBER() function, and then selecting the rows based on their row positioning. However, I get the following **error**:

> SQL compilation error: Window function [ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE.SALARY_GRADE_ID ASC 
>   NULLS LAST)] appears outside of SELECT, QUALIFY, and ORDER BY clauses.

**The query:**

```
SELECT Employee.Salary_Grade_Id, SUM(Salary_Grades.Grade_Amount) AS total, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER 
BY Employee.Salary_Grade_Id) AS rowCol FROM Employee, Salary_Grades 
WHERE (Employee.Salary_Grade_Id = Salary_Grades.Grade_Id AND rowCol = 1) GROUP BY 
Employee.Salary_Grade_Id;
```

What doesn't make sense is that when I remove the `AND rowCol = 1`, the query works with no errors. But with it, I get the error. What is going on here?

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your issue is that `rowCol` is an alias for a window function (`ROW_NUMBER()`) and they cannot appear in a `WHERE` clause. You can use a [`QUALIFY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify) clause instead:

```
SELECT Employee.Salary_Grade_Id, 
       SUM(Salary_Grades.Grade_Amount) AS total, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Employee.Salary_Grade_Id) AS rowCol 
FROM Employee, Salary_Grades 
WHERE (Employee.Salary_Grade_Id = Salary_Grades.Grade_Id)
GROUP BY Employee.Salary_Grade_Id
QUALIFY rowCol = 1
```

Note that you should use explicit `JOIN` syntax and rewrite the query as

```
SELECT Employee.Salary_Grade_Id, 
       SUM(Salary_Grades.Grade_Amount) AS total, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Employee.Salary_Grade_Id) AS rowCol 
FROM Employee
JOIN Salary_Grades ON Employee.Salary_Grade_Id = Salary_Grades.Grade_Id
GROUP BY Employee.Salary_Grade_Id
QUALIFY rowCol = 1
```

Comment: Ooh, QUALIFY is a nice extension to SQL.

Comment: @LiamClarke yes it is! It makes writing this sort of query a *lot* easier.

Comment: Oh my!  This one is nice.  I was unaware of this little handy tidbit.  Thanks!  I normally use what wrote out.

Answer (score 5):

The WHERE clause is applied before the windowing is, so you can't refer to a windowing function in the WHERE clause. You need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    grade_id, 
    sum(grade_amount) as total
FROM (
    SELECT
        Employee.Salary_Grade_Id as grade_id, 
        Salary_Grades.Grade_Amount AS grade_amount, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Employee.Salary_Grade_Id) AS rowCol 
    FROM Employee JOIN Salary_Grades ON Employee.Salary_Grade_Id = Salary_Grades.Grade_Id) x
WHERE  rowCol = 1
GROUP BY grade_id;
```

I also moved your join predicate up into the FROM clause as a best practice to avoid accidental cartesian joins if the predicate `Employee.Salary_Grade_Id = Salary_Grades.Grade_Id` was ever removed by mistake.

Comment: This is way to go for standard SQL.

Comment: Thanks Liam. If I'm not mistaken, you are using a subquery here which acts as a derived table?